# Using gio.lookup_by_address

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions, gio, gjs

Most of the code is borrowed, JS is not my way, but an extension needs to be created.

Can you tell me how to use `g_resolver_lookup_by_name()` to return IP within the given code?

[g-resolver-lookup-by-name](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GResolver.html#g-resolver-lookup-by-name)

```
const Main = imports.ui.main;
const St = imports.gi.St;
const GObject = imports.gi.GObject;
const Gio = imports.gi.Gio;
const PanelMenu = imports.ui.panelMenu;
const PopupMenu = imports.ui.popupMenu;
const Me = imports.misc.extensionUtils.getCurrentExtension();

let myPopup;

const MyPopup = GObject.registerClass(
class MyPopup extends PanelMenu.Button {

  _init () {
    super._init(0);
 ...
    this.menu.addMenuItem(
      new PopupMenu.PopupMenuItem(
        "Some : ", // IP is required to be returned
        {reactive : false},
      )
    );    
  }
});
...
```

`Gio.Resolver.lookup_by_name('google.com')` - TypeError: Gio.Resolver.lookup_by_name is not a function

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call a method as though it is static, but you first need to get the default resolver:

```js
const Gio = imports.gi.Gio;

// The default resolver
const resolver = Gio.Resolver.get_default();
```

Looking up a name will certainly do blocking I/O so using the async variant will be necessary in a Shell extension. A promise wrapper is probably best:

```js
function lookupName(host, cancellable = null) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolver.lookup_by_name_async(host, cancellable, (obj, res) => {
            try {
                resolve(resolver.lookup_by_name_finish(res));
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Of course, as the documentation says this will return a list of [`Gio.InetAddress`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/gio20/gio.inetaddress) objects, which you will have to call `to_string()` on to get a readable address.

Comment: Excuse me, but I still get `[object Promise]` even when using `toString ()`

Comment: Correct, the example function I gave returns a Promise. You'll have to resolve it with the `await` keyword or the `then()` instance method. See https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the above answer:
You do not actually need to implement a promise wrapper anymore.
GJS has a builtin function to make the async methods return a promise.

Inside your extention, you can determine the addresses that match a hostname like this:

1. Make the `lookup_by_name_async` method return a `Promise`

```js
Gio._promisify(Gio.Resolver.prototype, 'lookup_by_name_async', 'lookup_by_name_finish');
```

2. Initialize a resolver in your extention (probably somewhere during the `enable()` function).

```js
const resolver = Gio.Resolver.get_default();
```

3. Define an async function to lookup the addresses matching the hostname and return them as an array of strings

```js
async function lookupHostName(resolver, hostname, cancellable=null){
    let inetAddressList = await resolver.lookup_by_name_async(hostname, null);
    let addressesAsStrings = inetAddressList.map(address => address.to_string());
    return addressesAsStrings;
}
```

4. Call your function where you need it and work with the addresses

```js
lookupHostName(resolver, "localhost").then(ipAddresses => {
        log(JSON.stringify(ipAddresses));
    });
```

In your log you should then see something like the following:

```
["::1","127.0.0.1"]
```